# Returning an error in RX and Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.reactive, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a signalr (.Net Core version) hub that returns a stream of data using IObservable. This is pretty much lifted directly from this streaming sample:
https://github.com/radu-matei/signalr-samples/tree/master/streaming/web

```
public IObservable<MyStreamItem> StreamData(SomeRequestData request)
{}
```

I would like to validate that the incoming request is OK. Just standard validation stuff. Valid emails, dates, etc

So I am trying to use Observable.Throw to communicate this error back down to the client

```
public IObservable<MyStreamItem> StreamData(SomeRequestData request)
{
    if (!IsValid(request))
    {
        return Observable.Throw<MyStreamItem>(new Exception("Invalid Request"));
    }   
}
```

Is this the way to do it?
The error message is somehow lost in the comms to the browser, and so the stream is terminated, but no error message is sent to the client

I initially tried to do this in some middleware, but it seems that only the initial creation of the websocket gets captured by Middleware, not the subsequent call

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the code when you subscribe to the `IObservable` ? I'm having hard time believing that SignalR can properly serialize the `IObservable`. I also don't believe that any notifications done at the Hub are automatically emitted to subscriptions at SignalR clients in this example. The example feels weird and lacking ...then again, it's been a while since I worked with SignalR.

Comment: it's exactly the same as in the sample posted above

Comment: My mistake. SignalR has come a long way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is a pull request out now to propagate the exception from the Stream hub method to the client open right now. It will be in the Preview1 release of SignalR Core which will be released soon. 
Link to the pull request: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/1331

Answer (score 1):

To help with your knowledge of Rx I'm going to suggest that you rewrite `StreamData`. The current implementation creates a problem when there is some time between calling `StreamData` and subscribing to the resulting stream. It might be that the request isn't valid when `StreamData` is called, but shortly afterwards, and before the subscription, it is.

Here's how you could write it:

```
public IObservable<MyStreamItem> StreamData(SomeRequestData request)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        if (!IsValid(request))
        {
            return Observable.Throw<MyStreamItem>(new Exception("Invalid Request"));
        }
        else
            //return observable when request is valid
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it the same way as in the sample you linked, this should do it:

```
observer.OnError(new Exception("Invalid Request"));
```

In the sample, he has the error function wrong (named 'err'). It should be:

```
error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

To accommodate passing exceptions, I'd change the above and just send another `OnNext`, but pass an object like this:

**StreamingHub**

```
public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Exception Error { get; set; }
}

public IObservable<Message> StartStreaming()
{
    return Observable.Create(
        async (IObserver<Message> observer) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                observer.OnNext(new Message { Text = $"sending...{i}" });
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            observer.OnNext(new Message { Error = new Exception("Invalid Request") });
        });
```

**index.html**

```
function onStreamReceived(data){
    if (data.text) {
        console.log("received: " + data.text);
        var liElement = document.createElement('li');
        liElement.innerHTML = '<strong>' + "received" + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data.text;
        document.getElementById('discussion').appendChild(liElement);
    }
    if (data.error) {
        console.log("error: " + data.error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I fixed that. Even with that changed, the error message isnt propgated down to the client

Comment: If I throw a normal exception it is. If I use Obervable.Throw it is no

Comment: It just says the Channel has been closed. But I want to communicate the validation errors

Comment: That's not how you are meant to propagate errors in RX. It doesnt make sense to do it OnNext. That is meant to the next message in the stream - thanks tho'

Comment: TBH, I'm not even sure if this is the best way to inform the client of Validation errors. I'm sure there is probably a better way. so open to suggestions

Comment: I'm just answering your question. If you want suggestions as to the best approach to take, you can ask another question, although that may get closed for being opinion-based. Anyway, if you think the answer addressed the question, accept it.

Comment: The actual issue is that SignalR is grabbing the wrong exception message so when you use Observable.Throw it only looks at the top level exception instead of the innerException which has the custom exception message from the throw

Comment: hi @Brennan , this is meant to be fixed in preview 1, but there still appears to be a problem - see the comment I left on this issue. Can you let me know if it's a SignalR issue, or if it is something I am misundeerstanding - thanks https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/pull/1331